# File Comparison in Ruby Program

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.9.3

Is there a plugin/gem that i can use to compare two files inside Ruby code and return the differences?
Or is there some tool which i can integrate with Ruby and call in ruby code?

Comment: I thought diff is used for comparison of strings or arrays and not files. can i use diff for files too?

Comment: I meant the diff tool, if you're on Unix/Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you may use this library: https://github.com/samg/diffy